# jquery is not working in VS but its working in jsfiddle.net

Tags: jquery, landscape, jsfiddle, portrait

here is the jquery

```
$('#pl').find('img').each(function(i, elem) {
    var $this = $(this),
    ratio = $this.width() / $this.height();

    $this.addClass((ratio < 1) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="pl">
<img src="#" width="60" height="30" />
<img src="#" width="30" height="60" />
<img src="#" width="40" height="80" />
<img src="#" width="90" height="50" />
<img src="#" width="60" height="30" />
<img src="#" width="40" height="80" />
</div>
```

and here's the example in jsfiddle.net >>> [SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dYah8/1/)

Comment: did u add jquery in your html

Comment: @balachandran You should have checked the fiddle provided by him before posting this kind of crackPOT's comment..!

Comment: may be your code is not in a dom ready handler - the script in fiddle by default executes in a `window.onload()` handler. So move your code to a dom ready handler like `jQuery(function($){ ...your code... })`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  can you tel me if the code is working in jsfiddle not in other ..what are the possibility issue is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Jquery in Head

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(window).load(function () {
     $('#pl').find('img').each(function (i, elem) {
         var $this = $(this),
             ratio = $this.width() / $this.height();

         $this.addClass((ratio < 1) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
     });
 });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the document ready function

Add the script tag in your head part of the html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and your script be inside the document ready function

```
$(function() {

$('#pl').find('img').each(function(i, elem) {
    var $this = $(this),
    ratio = $this.width() / $this.height();

    $this.addClass((ratio < 1) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
});

});
```